# How to get all packages in an Artifactory repository

Tags: repository, artifactory, wget

I have created the repository remote in Artifactory, and I would like to say an artifact will get me all the packages that are in the manufacturer (the URL I entered when creating this repository) so I tried to do a `wget -r "https://login:token@URL_DU_REPO_Arti"`, but nothing downloads.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

By using Artifactory, we can proxy the remote registry and resolve them through it and store them locally. It means that the artifacts from the upstream registry(Ex: Dockerhub, NPMJS, Maven Central) will be fetched only if the client(Ex: Docker, Jenkins) requests for it. Artifactory doesn't have any mechanism to clone the entire upstream registry content.

I would like to explain the requirement with a use case in detail. Just for an example, I want to clone whatever is there in the upstream registry Dockerhub in Artifactory. The Dockerhub will have terabytes of data and we do not need that much content in our system. In real-time, the requirement is to fetch the artifacts which are needed through Artifactory and cache them in the remote repository cache of Artifactory.

Comment: Hi @Tatao Van thank you for your answer, ok, so that means it's not possible, we have to go each time to do a "wget" or "curl" to get the package we need

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. If you are doing a specific build(Ex: Maven), the required artifacts and their dependencies will be pulled from the remote registry configured inside Artifactory. If you triggered the same build, again and again, Artifactory will serve those artifacts from its remote cache.